# Postgis 2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 Server without X11

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, postgresql

Is it possible to install `postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3` (Postgres 9.5, Postgis 2.3) on Ubuntu 16.04 Server without installing `x11-common`?

After I installed Postgresql 9.5, I attempted to install `postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3`. This stated that I needed to install a large stack of dependencies including: `x11`, `libgl`, `libpulse`, `libqt` and others.

This is pretty crazy in my opinion as a simple `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3` results in an additional 590 MB install.

Comment: can you tell us why you need exactly this combination?

Comment: I agree with RoVo I can't find anything to even substantiate this problem, and I'm looking at the packages themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS is a PostgreSQL spatial extension that provides new geometry types and spatial functions on these types. Functionally, I can't see why it would require `libqt`, or other GUI libraries, except for auxiliary programs perhaps. (Are you sure these dependencies are not from other things like qgis?)

I don't have 16.04 now, but installing on a fresh 18.04 does not seem to require `libqt`, and the following did not report anything:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4 -s | grep libqt
```

Anyways, if you need PostGIS with minimum dependency on a Ubuntu server, you can build from source. It is not very difficult to install/build GEOS and several dependent libraries and then PostGIS itself. See e.g. [the instructions here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS24Debian9src).

Answer (score 3):

If the package developer says his/her package depends on "x11, libgl, libpulse, libqt and others", believe him/her.

How would one use `postgis` without `X11`?

Comment: Why should one 'just believe' a package author if a database extension tries to install a whole windowing system? There is no obvious reason why those dependencies are needed. It even tries to install mysql-common. What?!?! Installing a Postgres extension installs mysql? This at least needs some clarification.

Comment: use `apt-get source postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3` and you can figure out yourself.